# Cannot uninstall NetBeans 7.3

Tags: netbeans-7, uninstallation, netbeans6.8

I'm not able to  uninstall **NetBeans IDE 7.3** from my PC. It's showing "instance of the program is still running" even after I close all the background processes of the IDE. Can anyone help me??

Comment: Have you tried killing the JRE processes as well? NetBeans is written (and runs) entirely in Java.

Answer (score 15):

For windows, go to appdata/ roaming/netbeans and delete the lock file

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu users, go to `/Home/.netbeans/.YOUR_IDE_VERSION` there you will find `.lock` file and simply remove it.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows and any Netbeans version,

Go to location "C:\Users\< UserName >\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\< Version >" and remove the .lock file

Sometimes "AppData" is hidden, you have to unhide.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows,

Go to location "C:\Users\< UserName >\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3" and remove the .lock file

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Task Manager and end all the tasks related to NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Go to location "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3" and remove the .lock file
BUT SOME TIME THIS FILE MAY NOT SEE, SO GO TO PROPERTIES AND DISABLE HIDDEN FILE 
SO AppData FOLDER WILL SEE AND PROCEED AS BEFORE